# Does Magento 2 Open Source (CE) supports B2B?

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, b2b

Does Magento `Open Source 2.2.2` supports **Integrated B2B** functionality? If not how could we integrate B2B with Open Source where it supports different features like below

1. Customers can add products by SKU
2. Allow business customers with the ability create company accounts,
   set up multiple buyers, and define their specific roles and
   responsibilities with easy self-service tools
3. Create custom catalogs and price lists

Answer (score 2):

Here answer is simple no,

Magento by default does not provide this features.

For this purpose you can use Marketplace extension that converts your store to marketplace

Here are some example extension you can use for your purpose

https://github.com/amitshree/magento2-marketplace

https://github.com/turgayozgur/magento2-c2c

https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-Marketplace.html

https://www.apptha.com/magento-2/marketplace

Hope this info will help you

check above extension and see which extension can provide you best service as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with Martuza answers, but you are missing CedCommerce, 
https://www.cedcommerce.com/magento-2-extensions/marketplace " it's proving affordable pricing packages.... "

Comment: there are still some more if we could find :)